# PostgreSQL, CASE WHEN and IF

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with some cities, restaurants and orders (per restaurant) for a specific year. 
From this dataset, I have a problem stating that:

- In cities with average orders higher than 120, restaurants with less than 100 order should be aborted.
- In cities with average orders higher than 60, restaurants with less than 40 order should be aborted.
- In cities with average orders higher than 30, restaurants with less than 20 order should be aborted.

Until now, I have created a query that can give me a table with the average orders for each city and label them as 1, 2, 3 or 4 as follows:

```
SELECT cities, AVG(orders), COUNT(restaurants),
      CASE 
         WHEN (AVG(orders) >= 120) THEN '1'
         WHEN (120 > AVG(orders) >= 60) THEN '2'
         WHEN (60 > AVG(orders) >= 30) THEN '3'
         ELSE '4'
         END AS ranking
FROM c_cities
GROUP BY 1
```

So, now I want to create a statement that will check for example: 
for rating = 1, if orders > 100 -> keep them or label them as something.
for rating = 2, if orders > 60 -> similar and etc.

I am trying to find the logic and the right statement in it. 
I think that a CASE ... WHEN cannot solve my problem.
I am reading the documentation for IF statement, but I cannot make it work.

I would be grateful for any help you could provide :)

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output based on that data (_formatted_ text please, no screenshots. Or even better: `create table` and `insert` statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow the logic in your bullet points, but not the rest of the question.  To implement that logic, use window functions and then `where`.  For instance, the following gets the restaurants that should be "aborted" according to your definition:

```
select cr.*
from (select c.city, c.restaurant, avg(orders) as restaurant_avg,
             (sum(orders) over (partition by city) /
              count(distinct restaurant) over (order by city)
             ) as city_avg
      from c_cities
      group by c.city, c.restaurant
     ) cr
where (city_avg > 120 and restuarant_avg < 100) or
      (city_avg > 100 and restaurant_avg < 80) or
      (city_avg > 30 and restaurant_avg < 20);
```

The idea is to get the city and restaurant average calculated for each row.  Then you can just compare them.

Comment: cool :) Actually partition by is what I was looking for :) Thanks a lot!